# SQL AND Clause only if another value exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a basic SQL query where I am selecting data from a core records table. I want to add an `AND` clause to my statement to filter out the results based on a table variable, only if data actually exists in there.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE 
    field = '123'
AND
    (gender IN (SELECT gender FROM @genders))
```

In this case, I am looking for all records where `field = 123`. My goal here is to say that if `@genders` contains records, filter by that as well.

However, if `@genders` is empty and we don't have any data in it, it should include all records.

How can I go about doing this? The temp tables are created based on the user selecting one or more **optional** pieces of criteria from the UI. If they choose a gender for example, I put their selections into a temp table and then I need to search records that meet that criteria. However, if they don't select a gender, I want to include all records, regardless of what the main record has for the gender field.

Comment: Couldn't you just do a LEFT JOIN of @genders on your table TABLE

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to think this is odd but it is efficient

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM TABLE t
JOIN GENDERS g 
  on g.gender = t.gender 
 and t.field = '123'
union all 
SELECT t.* 
FROM TABLE t
where not exists (select 1 from genders)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE 
    field = '123'
AND ((SELECT count(1) FROM @genders) = 0 OR
    (gender IN (SELECT gender FROM @genders)))
```

Comment: I think `0 = 0` would be simplier condition :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use IF condition:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT gender FROM @genders)
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM TABLE
  WHERE field = '123'
  AND
  (gender IN (SELECT gender FROM @genders))
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT *  FROM TABLE
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm under-thinking it, but isn't it just this?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    TABLE AS t
LEFT JOIN
    @genders AS g
        ON
            g.gender = t.gender
WHERE 
    field = '123'
    AND
    (g.gender = t.gender OR g.gender IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query doesn't get too complicated, I'd recommend an `if` statement. Once you find yourself continually adding `if else` statement in there, I'd recommend looking into dynamic SQL.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT gender FROM @genders)
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM TABLE
  WHERE field = '123'
  and gender IN (SELECT distinct gender FROM @genders)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE field = '123'
END
```